# Запуск программы через консольное приложение

Tags: visual-c++, c++

Есть программа. Я хочу сделать консольное приложение, которое запускало бы её. Как это сделать?

Для разработки используется вижуал студио.

(*Мне нужно защитить программу от не лицензионного использования. Для этого я пишу приложение, которое создает файл, без которого не может работать программа. Далее это приложение должно запускать exe-файл. Все это оно (консольное приложение) делает, разумеется, лишь в случае, когда выполняются необходимые условия.*)

Answer (score 3):

```
system("app.exe");
```

Answer (score 3):

[@Андрей Алексеев](/users/11022/%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B5%D0%B2), и в винде это тоже работает

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define check_is_OK() (1)

main ()
{
  if (check_is_OK())
      execl("c:/Documents and Settings/avp/src/hashcode/a.exe","xaxa",0);
  printf ("Not working...\n");
  exit(-1);
}
```

Если коротко, программа в том же процессе меняет свой код. Или другими словами вызывает исполняемый модуль, а сама завершается.

В данном случае вызванный .exe модуль будет видеть свое имя не `c:\Documents and Settings\avp\src\hashcode\a.exe` а `xaxa`.

Подробней о функциях семейства exec прочтите `man 2 execl`

Comment: @avp: исходя из Visual Studio и сложности вопроса, у ТС могут возникнуть проблемы с `man`.

+1 за кроссплатформенное решение и замещение процесса.

ЗЫ: а не нужно ли всё же указать тип возвращаемого значения функции?

Comment: У ТС Visual Studio, unistd.h там нет, выдернутый же с MinGW или Cygwin она наотрез откажется воспринимать.

Comment: Вообще говоря, я нашел только одну библиотеку, предоставляющую относительно кроссплатформенный способ запуска процессов - `Poco`, класс `Process`.

Comment: @mikillskegg Есть ещё boost::process (но он не входит в официальный boost). Ну а для озвученной ТС задачи и простого system(...) хватит, тоже вполне себе кроссплатформенно.

Comment: @mikillskegg: приведёте пример с POCO? Для истории.

Comment: @VladD, почему для истории? Разве POCO умер?

@falstaf, можно ссылочку?

Comment: @mikillskegg http://www.highscore.de/boost/process/

Comment: @mikillskegg: я плохо сформулировал. Имелось в виду, что топикстартеру это, вероятно, не пригодится, зато будущим поколениям участников сайта -- вполне может быть.

Comment: Вот, самый простой
    
     #include <Poco/Process.h>
     using namespace ::Poco;

     int main() {
   Process::Args args;
   args.push_back ("www.mail.ru");
   args.push_back ("hashcode.ru"); 
   ProcessHandle handler = Process::launch ("google-chrome", args);
   handler.wait();
     }

Comment: @falstaf, спасибо. Хотя я бы пока им пользовался с осторожностью. Все-таки неофициальная библиотека, неизвестно, какие там баги. А Poco довольно качественная и стабильная.

Comment: @mikillskegg, согласен, об этом говорит хотя бы тот факт, что у автора уже несколько лет не доходят руки допилить библиотеку, дабы её заапрувили в boost. Впрочем, несмотря на это, народ отзывается о ней довольно положительно. Сам не знаю, не использовал.

Comment: @mikillskegg: спасибо!

Comment: А мне кажется, если инструмент (в данном случае VS) не понимает POSIX, то лучше сменить инструмент.

А man-ы легко смотрятся через гугл.

Answer (score 2):

Использовать [CreateProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx) (еще одно [описание](http://vsokovikov.narod.ru/New_MSDN_API/Process_thread/fn_createprocess.htm) ) или на худой конец [WinExec](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687393(v=vs.85).aspx), но это уже устаревшее считается.

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете воспользоваться функцией [`CreateProcess`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682425%28VS.85%29.aspx). Но я не думаю, что таким образом вы получите сколько-нибудь хорошую защиту.

Comment: там особо сложная и не нужна. Цена не так высока, что бы пытались взломать её. 
Она имеет узкую направленность.

Comment: @Андрей Алексеев: а на чём основывается защита? Если уж кто-то будет копировать, скопирует и консольное приложение.

Comment: для энтузиастов цена не имеет значения ) самое узкое место - проверка лицензии, да и так просто открывать .exe вам множество антивирусов и не дадут.

Comment: @VladD, защита основана на времени. месяц. 
эта программа не нужна без платы, которую мы(У меня на работе) выпускаем. она написана специально под эту плату.
а защита основана на времени.т.е. будет файл тхт, в котором есть начальная дата лицензии и конечная.
каждый раз, когда мы будем заходить, программа будет перезаписывать начальную дату. т.е. изменение даты в компьютере не поможет.

а защита не от копирования, а от долгого времени использования.

Comment: @Андрей Алексеев: А зачем для этого отдельная утилита командной строки? Проверяйте всё в главной программе, делов-то!

Answer (score 0):

[@VladD](/users/10105/vladd), что бы не колечить программу. Через месяц, если заплатят деньги (условия-50% суммы до, 50% после), надо оставить программу  без проверки. Конечно можно оставить условие проверки, но это лишние затраты. Программы работают под ОООЧЕНЬ старые компьютеры.

Comment: Нееее, мне кажется, всё не так трагично. Условие наверняка проверяется за пару микросекунд, никто и не заметит. Кроме того, расходы на запуск нового процесса куда больше, чем на элементарную проверку, _особенно_ на старых компьютерах. Так что никакой выгоды не видно, одни недостатки.

Comment: Ок-ок)
убедили-запускаю все в том же приложении

Comment: @andrw: теперь надо ещё убедить топикстартера :)

Comment: @VladD, убедили :D
я когда привязывал этот этот Аккаунт к фэйсбуку, то почему то повторно зарегистрировался Аккаунт на ту же почту..

Comment: @ХэшКод, @andrw: надо бы сообщить модераторам, пусть соединят экаунты.

Comment: VladD, я писал в службу поддержки, но мне не ответили..

Comment: @andrw: может, сейчас обратят внимание, упомянул @ХэшКод'a в комментарии, ему должно прийти извещение.

Comment: Надеюсь! спасибо:)
@VladD